# rails accessing value from facebooker hash/array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

This is my first time using the facebooker plugin with rails, and I'm having trouble accessing user info.  The website uses FB connect to authenticate users.

I am trying to get the name of the university that the logged in user attends.

When I use the command   `<%= facebook_session.user.education_history[:name] %>`, I get an error "Symbol as array index".

I have also tried using `education_history[1`], but that just returns 
"# `Facebooker::EducationInfo:<some sort of alphanumeric  hash value>`"

When I use something like   `<%= facebook_session.user.relationship_status %>` , it returns the relationship status just fine. 
Similarly, 
`<%= facebook_session.user.hometown_location.city %>` returns the city name just fine.

I've checked out the documentation for facebooker, but I can't figure out the correct way to get the values I need.

Any idea on how to get this to work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`facebook_session.user.education_history` returns an array of [`Facebooker::EducationInfo`](http://facebooker.rubyforge.org/classes/Facebooker/EducationInfo.html) objects. The proper way to access it would be:

```
ed = facebook_session.user.education_history.last #Will be nil if not provided
@ed_name = ed.name unless ed.nil?
```

I am not sure the order they are sorted in, so you may need to call `.first` instead of `.last`